# How to use latest props in render() after componentDidUpdate()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-component

When my component mounts, I call an API to get a list of people via axios in the redux store.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.getPeople();
}
```

Basically, once API call is successful, I will update the `peopleList` state in the redux store with the latest data.

Now I map over this `peopleList` (via mapStatetoProps) to generate a list of people in my component's `render()`. All is good up to this point.

However, each person card has a 'like' button which in turn does a POST request to change the people object's `isLiked` property to 'true' (and also makes all the other people object `'isLiked'` property to false (only one can be liked at a time)).

Now, when I click the 'like' button, it only triggers the change in the backend. I have to refresh the page to see the updated rendered UI.

I am new to React and I can see that when I do a `componentDidUpdate()`, I have access to the new data upon clicking the 'like' button, as in:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {

    if(this.props.people !== prevProps.people) {
        console.log("PREV");
        console.log(prevProps.people);
        console.log("LATEST");
        console.log(this.props.people);
    }

}
```

My problem is how do I get my render method to use the latest props instead of the one it rendered during `componentDidMount()` upon click?

Comment: `this.props` is the latest one. You can use it in the `render` method.

Comment: Are you sure that you are updating your refux state? If you did so, a call to render should be triggered automatically and the view should be updated. Can you show your component code?

Comment: @AnthonyRaymond Since my this.props.people is getting its data from the redux state, and I can see that it changed when I do componentDidUpdate, wouldnt that mean that the redux state has really updated?

Comment: To fully and correctly answer you question, we need to see your reducer and selector (mapStateToProps). render should always automatically get the latest props, if redux state is changed.Can you update you question with this information?

Comment: @catandmouse i does. To help you we're gonna need the code for the component + what StephanHovius asked for

Answer (score 0):

You need not wanna update it manually just make sure the `getPeople` action updates the `peopleList` in your Redux state. If it does, then the React component automatically re-renders the DOM after `componentDidUpdate`.